# 19 digit number doesn't get parsed as is in R

Tags: r, json, numeric, biginteger

I have the following number in JSON in a character array:

> [1544018118438041139,162.0,38.0,0.023529414,1.0,2131230815,1]

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(
  '[1544018118438041139,162.0,38.0,0.023529414,1.0,2131230815,1]'
)
```

returns:

> [1] 1544018118438041088.000000000000000000000
>   162.000000000000000000000                  38.000000000000000000000 [4]                   0.023529413999999998497
>   1.000000000000000000000          2131230815.000000000000000000000 [7]                   1.000000000000000000000

I want it to return the right exact time (the big number: 1544018118438041139)

Please advise how to make it work.

Comment: You should tell us from which package `fromJSON` is.

Comment: I am using the jsonlite package @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The JSON standard (ECMA-404) does not specify the range of numbers that are valid JSON but the website suggests it to be “very much like a C or Java number”, which would make this JSON snippet unspecified because C and Java numeric types have the same precision issues as R. This implies that Tim’s suggested answer is the best bet at producing reproducible, compatible results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a limit in precision inherent in R itself.  Consider:

```
x <- 1544018118438041139
as.character(x)

[1] "1544018118438041088"
```

So, I'm not sure that the `jsonlite` package is responsible for this rounding error.  Based on the @Konrad comment, this is a limit in precision of the IEEE data type.

There is a workaround if all you want to do is preserve the digits in the original number.  You could instead treat the data as a string:

```
'["1544018118438041139",162.0,38.0,0.023529414,1.0,2131230815,1]'
```

Then, presumably `jsonlite` would read in the "number" as a string, without any precision issues coming into play.  But then you would still have the problem should you decide to cast to numeric in R and do math with it.

Comment: And what will be the solution? To use gmp package and as.bigz?

Comment: It’s not a rounding error, it’s the limited precision of the IEEE data type (this is probably what you mean but “rounding” implies a lossy mathematical operation whereas this is just a format restriction).